# Term for reciprocal percentage

Tags: logarithms, terminology, percentages

I find myself struggling to succinctly express the concept of gain or loss percentages that are equivalent in the sense that they are reciprocal.  For instance, take the following sentence:

> An investor with log-utility will experience the same magnitude of utility change for a gain or loss of a certain percentage of wealth.

What is intended is that the investor would lose as much utility from a 20% decrease in wealth as they would gain from a 25% increase (because (1+25%)=1/(1+-20%)).  Obviously, I can say "change in log" but that makes the above sentence feel redundant.  And I could also say "for percentage gains or losses that are reciprocal when added to unity", but that's pretty verbose.
Is there a nice succinct term/way to express this idea of "same" reciprocal percentages?

Answer (score 1):

The log-utility function is $U(c)=\log(c)$ where $c$ is the investor's wealth.
We know that
$$
\frac{dU(c)}{dc}=\frac{1}{c}\,.
$$
In other words, the *absolute* change $dU$ of the utility under an *absolute* change $dc$ of wealth is
$$
dU=\frac{dc}{c}\,.
$$
The right hand side of this is obviously the *relative* change of wealth.

In words: the *absolute* change of log-utility equals the *relative* change of wealth, regardless if the latter is a gain or a loss.

Regarding your numerical example. The relation
$$
1+25\%=\frac{1}{1-20\%}\,.
$$
says nothing else than a $25\%$ increase of wealth followed by a $20\%$ loss brings us back to the initial wealth $c_0$:
$$
c_1=c_0(1+25\%)\,,\quad\quad c_2=c_1(1-20\%)=c_0(1+25\%)(1-20\%)=c_0\,.
$$
I'd say that is is the succint way of expressing "same reciprocal percentage".

Closely related to this is the following asymmetry of the log-utility:
The corresponding log-utility does *not* got back to the initial utility:
$$
U_1=U_0+25\%\,,\quad\quad U_2=U_1-20\%=U_0+5\%\,.
$$
This happens only when an *absolute* gain is followed by an equal *absolute* loss. The log-utility function has an asymmetry which is used to model
[risk aversion](https://eintalu.medium.com/some-simple-utility-functions-cc04c545ce02).